# Why doesn't M-v following C-v move cursor back to the original position?

Tags: scrolling, cursor, motion

<kbd>M-v</kbd> following <kbd>C-v</kbd> doesn't move the cursor back to the original position. Why is that? Can we make it happen?

Answer (score 13):

You can try setting `scroll-preserve-screen-position` to `always`:

```el
(setq scroll-preserve-screen-position 'always)
```

From the documentation (`C-h v scroll-preserve-screen-position`):

> Controls if scroll commands move point to keep its screen position unchanged.
>   A value of `nil` means point does not keep its screen position except
>   at the scroll margin or window boundary respectively.
>   A value of `t` means point keeps its screen position if the scroll
>   command moved it vertically out of the window, e.g. when scrolling
>   by full screens.
>   Any other value means point always keeps its screen position.
>   Scroll commands should have the `scroll-command` property
>   on their symbols to be controlled by this variable.